# Increase default UITableView Scroll Speed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, scroll

I have an app that has a lot of images surfaced via UITableView. I want the user to be able to scroll through these faster than the default scroll speed  e.g. if the user scrolls 1 screen pixel down then the UITableView should scroll 2 pixels down.

Seems like this should be provided already instead of messing around with offsets in scrollViewDidScroll. Any recommendations?

Comment: Nope. Use `scrollViewDidScroll`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no build-in way to control the speed of scrolling. You can either add your custom logic to `scrollVieWDidScroll` or you can implement `sectionIndexTitlesForTableView` and provide user with a quick scroll based on some grouping (like letters in standard Contacts app)